# Nginx - Disable cache for XHR Request

Tags: apache, caching, nginx

How I can disable the cache when the inbound request is XHR(ajax) with nginx(and if it possible, for Apache)?

The XHR has this https header:

```
X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for nginx, please try out the following code,

```
...
set $no_cache 0;
...
if ($http_x_requested_with ~* 'XMLHttpRequest') {
   set $no_cache 1;
}
...
location ~ \.php$ {
   ...
   fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
   ...
}
...
```

References: [Learn to implement caching in Nginx](https://www.techromance.com/2015/11/11/microcaching-nginx-web-server/), [fastcgi_no_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_no_cache)

Comment: The fastcgi_no_cache parameter will ensure the response is not cached if it would otherwise have been cached. However, if there is an existing cached response, it will serve that response. If you want to ensure that this is not the case, then you will need to add `fastcgi_cache_bypass  $no_cache;`. The combination of the fastcgi_no_cache and fastcgi_cache_bypass parameters gives fine grained control of caching behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

[It is generally a good idea to avoid `if` in nginx configuration files whenever possible](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). If you have any way to adapt the frontend, where the requests are sent from, try adding the current time as a GET variable (e.g. `myhost/?1475834405`). Since that URL hasn't been requested before, the cache won't be used.